# Can't connect to wireless network

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, 802.11g

I have HP Elitepad running Windows 8.1 which I am trying to connect to my wireless network (Linksys wrt54gl). When I try to connect, it takes a few minutes and then I get the message "Can't connect to this network".

I have no problems connecting my tablet to other networks and other devices (my iPhone 4S) to this network. I have tried disabling network security and using the network troubleshooting guide without success.

```
Device: HP ElitePad running Windows 8.1 
WiFi Adapter: Qualcomm Atheros AR6004 802.11a/b/g/n WiFi Adapter
Router: Linksys wrt54gl
```

Comment: Try updating the router firmware. That model appears to be fairly old.

Comment: Upgrading firmware did not help, but thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, changing "Wireless network mode" from "G-only" to "Mixed" (802.11g/b) helped. Which is very strange since the WiFi adapter has support for a/b/g/n and I have successfully connected to n-networks.

Comment: I had a similar case - my FRITZ!Box Wifi router was set to allow WPA2 only (no WPA); work laptop Win 8.1 could not connect, even though smartphone and home laptop Win7 connected fine. I temporarily set the WLAN router to allow WPA+WPA2, boom, work laptop also connects fine. Then I set it back to WPA2 only, and it still connects fine....